# Clair does not parse header files correctly for pointers in arguments

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, rascal

I am parsing a header file using Rascal ClaiR:

```
iFile = toLocation("file://D:/test.h");
ast = parseCpp(iFile);
iprint(ast);
```

The header file test.h looks as follows:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

/* Generic function */
result_t API get_data(query_h query, char **string, result_t *res);
result_t API   set_data(node_h node,   const char *string);
result_t API update_data(node_h node, char ***names, uint32_t *count);

#endif
```

As an outcome I get multiple errors like this:

- decl=|cpp+parameter:///update_data(org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.parser.ProblemType@53e470da,char.*.*.*,%3F.*)/count|),

Is this a bug in ClaiR?

Comment: This is a good question, but I see it as a bug report rather than a SO question. @Peter could you post it on GitHub instead at https://github.com/cwi-swat/clair/issues thanks for taking the time. It's appreciated!

Comment: @JurgenVinju: I created the issue. Thank you for the link!